# Find the sum of digits of $999...999^3$ (12 nines)

Tags: number-theory

What will be the sum of digits of the following expression? $$999999999999^3$$
Note that the base has $12$ nines.

Without doing it using brute force, is there an easy and simple method to find the sum of digits.

Also, in finding sum of digits of expressions like those, is there a *trick* that is used?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1913962/131263) and [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1915130/131263), which is a generalized version of the former.

Comment: @barakmanos great! Thanks a lot!